# .NET - Thread synchronization

Tags: c#, synchronization, multithreading

I've been working on a thread which will live as long as the application is running, and runs at a interval of 500ms. I noted that I could be uselessly processing if there's nothing in the queue for it to process, so I went around looking at some sources I had locally, and I found an example close to mine, but it's in Java.

The example had this:

```
synchronized(this) {
    try {
        wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        cleanup();
        break;
    }
}
```

Inside a while loop which goes on forever.

The thread has this to notify the wait:

```
synchronized(this) {
    notifyAll();
}
```

This was inside the enqueue thread.
I'd also like you to note that the class inherits Runnable.

Could anyone quickly explain the corresponding functions in C#? And maybe an example if you could!

Comment: You should consider using the thread pool instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET/C# best practice would be to use an [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx).

You'd have some variable shared between the threads as so:

```
EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
```

In the consumer thread (the one that you're waking up every 500ms right now), you'd loop waiting for the handle (perhaps with a timeout):

```
try
{
    while(true)
    {
        handle.WaitOne();
        doSomething();
    }
}
catch(ThreadAbortException)
{
    cleanup();
}
```

And in the producer thread:

```
produceSomething();
handle.Set();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a blocking queue : http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060414.asp

It's a  Queue except Dequeue function blocks until there is an object to return.

Usage:

```
BlockingQueue q = new BlockingQueue();

  void ProducerThread()
  {
    while (!done)
      {
        MyData d = GetData();
        q.Enqueue(d);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
  }

  void ConsumerThread()
  {
    while (!done)
      {
        MyData d = (MyData)q.Dequeue();
        process(d);
      }
  }
```

The consumer thread only executes when there is something in the queue to process, and doesn’t waste CPU time polling when there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer that fires every 500ms and let your timer handler do the work. Timer handler threads run in the thread pool. Read about it here: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Timers.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timer(500);
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler (MyTimerHandler);
timer.Start();

private void TimerHandler(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // optional - stop the timer to prevent overlapping events
    timer.Stop();
    // this is where you do your thing
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: For a timer that will continue to run for the entire duration of the process then using a `System.Threading.Timer` would be be a slightly more performant/efficient option.

Comment: @Yooder, not sure if it would be significantly more performant, but it would be much simpler to use.

Comment: Per the referenced Alahari paper: "... the System.Timers namespace. This simply wraps System.Threading.Timer, providing additional convenience while using the same thread pool ...". Why would there be a performance difference?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to download and read Joe Albahari's free ebook on threading in C#. It's a great introduction and reference.

[Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)